# Ember build for production not building properly

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am building my ember app in production environment and deploying it on my local wamp server(apache server). But when I copy the file and open the app using url, the handlebar template application.hbs or index.hbs is not rendered.

I am building my project using

```
ember build --environment production  --output-path dist/
```

But when I open the path 127.0.0.1/path-to-my-project
I get following error in console.

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-data/-private\system\references\record` imported from `ember-data/-private/system/references`   
vendor-192d3eef66f0205b64b4acf903f80f63.js:1
```

I am getting this error when building in production environment,building in development environment is working fine

I checked the documentation and sources available online, but couldn't find the cause for this error.
Please Help...

Comment: Seems related to dependencies, have you tried to remove them and reinstall?

Comment: Yes I tried that,..,,.but still getting the same error :( @locks

Comment: I am also seeing this exact issue

Comment: I've got the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, it's mixing / and \s.  See:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/4205

If you're using the latest Ember, the solution is to upgrade to Ember-Cli 2.4.2 and use Ember Data 2.4.0.

Comment: @SwastikRoy Glad that's sorted it for you.  Would you mind hitting the accept answer Tick so that anyone else can see the working solution immediately as well? Thanks.